# Pool system Mistake

Tags: python, python-requests, pool

I'm trying to add Pool system into my application but I think I'm doing something wrong.

My Code :

```
import requests, threading, platform, os
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool


if platform.system() == "Linux":
    clear = lambda: os.system('clear')
    clear()
if platform.system() == "Windows":
    clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
    clear()
        
            
def check(data):
    try:
        r = requests.get(data)
        if 'working ' in r.text:
            with open("working.txt", mode="a") as urlsvuln:
                print("Working : " + r.url)
                urlsvuln.write(r.url + "\n")
                         
        else:
            print("Not working")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)      


with open("texte.txt", mode="r") as mf:
    lines = mf.read().splitlines() 
    for line in lines:
        data = line + "'" 
        print(data)
try:    
    pp = Pool(10)
    pr = pp.map(check, data)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

So this code is working but I can see like if I have a text file with like 3 lines for see if url is working and I see my apps is doing like 10 times requests and also write 10x in my text.

Comment: Can you please explain what are you trying to do and what is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will achieve what you are trying to do

```
import requests, platform, os
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from io import StringIO

if platform.system() == "Linux":
    clear = lambda: os.system('clear')
    clear()
if platform.system() == "Windows":
    clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
    clear()


def check(data):
    try:
        r = requests.get(data, timeout=2)
        if r.text:
            out.write(f"Working {data}\n")
        else:
            out.write(f"Not working {data}\n")
    except Exception as e:
        out.write(f"Not working {data}\n")

urls = StringIO("https://www.google.com\nhttps://www.yahoo.com\nhttps://www.nonexistent.com")
# Note I am using in-memory file here but you can read the urls from file here
data = urls.read().splitlines()

try:
    with open("working.txt", mode="a") as out:
        pp = Pool(10)
        pr = pp.map(check, data)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Though `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` does the job here but I would highly recommend using `ThreadPoolExecutor` here to make it non blocking.

[ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor)